# Custom Cache Engine Not Working in CakePhp 2.6

Tags: php, cakephp, caching, zend-framework2

I'm trying to implement Zend Cache from ZF2 inside CakePhp to make use of it's tagging features, among others.

I created a class inside /app/Lib/Cache/Engine/ZendCacheEngine.php

```
class ZendCacheEngine extends CacheEngine {
   //All abstract functions from Cake's CacheEngine are 

    public function init($settings = array()){
        //Code here....
    }

    //Along with read, write, delete, etc...
}
```

For the time being, i only have a print "function name" inside these functions and a return. I did this in my efforts to debug what is going on.

Inside my bootstrap.php I set the config for my custom class:

```
Cache::config('custom_zend', array(
    'engine' => 'ZendCache',
    'duration' => '+1 hours',
    'probability' => 100,
));
```

When I try to use it inside my Controllers, the cache read and write functions are being ignored completely. (Function name not being printed in my case, except for the init function)

```
public function news($id, $something) {
        $result = Cache::read('news', 'custom_zend');
        if (!$result) {

            $result = $this->News->find('all'); // For the sake of simplicity here
            Cache::write('news', $result, 'custom_zend');
        }
        $this->set('news',$news);   
    }
```

Bottom line, I am assuming the file is in the correct place and the configuration is correct (since the init() function inside my custom class is being called).

I need to know why the actual read/write/etc... are not being called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the init() was not setting the $settings array properly, that's why the other functions were not being called.